# Docker-compose mount directory

Tags: docker-compose

ok this is driving me nuts already. What I just want to do is launch [php:5.6-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image and mount my `./web` to `/var/www/html` by having the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    apache:
        image: php:5.6-apache
        volumes: 
            - ./web:/var/www/html
        ports: 
            - 8081:80
```

Launching it with `docker-compose up`.

For some unknown reason this results in empty `/var/www/html` folder, although it should contain what I have in `./web`.

Or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: windows and docker is set to "Linux containers"

Comment: then on windows I would try `%cd%/web:/var/www/html` I had some strange problems with `.`. or try `"./web:/var/www/html"` too

Comment: it then complains that "ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 19"

Comment: did you tried also with the `"`?

Comment: solved this, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that for some reason windows firewall prevented folder sharing. It seems that it was because DockerNat network was listed among Public networks, so I had to run the following commands in elevated power shell:

```
$Profile = Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)"
$Profile.NetworkCategory = "Private"
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InputObject $Profile
```

Then I was able to enable drive sharing in docker settings and then mounted folders became filled with files.

**[UPDATE 2018-05-03]** There's a good [gist](https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/8b5b2ed9ff63de31045d41304e3915b3) that will put dockerNat network to private when you restart docker. All you have to do is modify **MobyLinux.ps1** file located at `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources` by adding [include at 86](https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/8b5b2ed9ff63de31045d41304e3915b3), [function at 182-186](https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/8b5b2ed9ff63de31045d41304e3915b3) and modifying lines [try/catch statement at 399-409](https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/8b5b2ed9ff63de31045d41304e3915b3) to include `Set-Switch-Private` function calls.